# How can I read datasources added to page in design time

Tags: c#, .net, datasource, web-controls

I'm developing a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` using C# and I want to read all datasources added to page, in design time.

How can I do this

Comment: Do you have a `DataSourceID` propperty?

Answer (score 0):

Just take the controls as the usual ones... if you have a text box with id 'txtName', then take its value as txtName.text.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? are you suggesting that I need to read page.datasources from a control created inside the page control tree to findout list of datasources like SqlDataSource added to page somewhere inside control tree of the page?